# Differntiability properties of kriging interpolation

Tags: probability, statistics, interpolation

What are the differentiability properties of Kriging interpolation functions?
Specifically, I am interested in using it to create a random realization of a 1D function using a regularly spaced grid of randomly drawn "data", with a given variogram, and crucially, I need it to be at least twice differentiable.

Comment: There are numerous Kriging methods. Can you be more specific? Is it ordinary kriging, indicator kriging, etc?

Comment: True, and now I am thinking of ordinary Kringing, but I am willing to adapt the implementation to whichever Kringing method can produce a twice differentiable realization of a random 1D signal with a given (i.e. user-specified) "data" points and variogram.

Comment: For 1 dimensional data, you can use time series methods as well.